# Using 'you' in scientific papers

Tags: pronouns, formality

In German, most of the time you try to avoid 'you' in academic papers. Of course I refer to 'you' in the meaning of 'in general' not you as a pronoun. What is the best practice in English?

Comment: Scientific papers often use passive constructions, which omit the person doing the action.

Comment: Please give an example of a typical sentence where this question arises for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in scientific register, the "**passive voice**" is preferred rather than the active voice. Hence, if you take a look at credible scientific journals, you see there's no need to use "**you**", whilst in German you could use "**man**" and "**passive voice**" in scientific papers.

Man in German corresponds (in terms of meaning) to:

- the English indefinite pronoun one (like doing one's homework). This is however more literary.
- the English passive voice

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who is meant by "you". If you are stating a principle which applies to anyone, such as:

> You cannot simply ignore facts which you find inconvenient.

You can simply switch to the formal literary pronoun "one":

> One cannot simply ignore facts which one finds inconvenient.

If though you wish to address the reader without seeming too familiar, you should address him in the third person:

> The reader will readily perceive the chief flaw of this argument.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I meant 'you'  as 'one'. Therefore is 'one' appropriate for academic papers?

Comment: Yes, 'one' is appropriate in any formal context.